# VB6 with Crystal Reports on Windows 2000 Terminal Services

Tags: windows, vb6, crystal-reports, windows-2000

We got an old app written in VB6, which uses Crystal Reports.

Is there a tool that would allow us in which permission the application is being denied to create the Crystal Report object?

We've narrowed it down to user permission issues, but it would not be right to provide users with Admin access levels to the application server.

Any advise highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Oh, geez ... I want to say that Crystal is trying to write to C:\WINNT\Temp\ or some directory like that when a report is generated. I remember way back when Crystal used to do something like this. It also never cleaned the temp files, so you may find them on your server.

Comment: I have actually set some user's login to have R/W access to that folder but still the creation of the Crystal report object is throwing the error of permission denied. I also have provided R/W access to the app's report folder, as well as System32 but still it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can will use sysinternals that is a suite of diagnostic's components. Look for regmon for view reads done for you program, that is a common problem other is complete installer crystal report in server (many time that terminate with the problem)

Comment: I am trying to use some SysInternals utilities but apparently, some of them only run on servers higher than Win2K. Lots of their apps are requesting for some DLLs that are non-existent in the Win2K server (i.e. credui.dll, etc..)

Comment: Will accept this as a valid answer, as what I did was tried to install the app into Win2K3 and was able to use SysInternals utilities.